# Вычислить суммы строк треугольника из индекса строки

Tags: java

нам дан треугольник

```
            1
         3     5
      7     9     11
   13    15    17   19
21    23    25    27   29
```

Нужно вычислить суммы строк этого треугольника из индекса строки (начиная с индекса 1), например:

```
rowSumOddNumbers(1); // 1
rowSumOddNumbers(2); // 3 + 5 = 8
```

треугольник в коде уже готов, но я запутался с "Нужно вычислить суммы строк этого треугольника из индекса строки". Скорее всего я неправильно понял вопрос. Буду благодарен, если кто-то поможет.

```
public class RowSumOddNumbers {
    public static void rowSumOddNumbers(int n) {
        int c = 5;
        for (int i = 0, num = 1; i < c; i++) {
            for (int l = c - i; l > 0; l--) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) {
                if (num < 11) {
                    System.out.print(num + "   ");
                    num += 2;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(num + "  ");
                    num += 2;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно не усложнять

```js
function rowSumOddNumbers(n) {
  return n * n * n
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Для суммы чисел в данной строке найдите в интернете формулу суммы членов арифметической прогрессии -

первый член: `n * n - n + 1`,

шаг: `2`,

количество членов: `n`,

где `n` - номер строки.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятна суть задачи. Если нужно зная номер строки посчитать её сумму, то это делается одной формулой:

**Будем считать, что строки нумеруются с 0**

Сумма элементов строки - арифметическая прогрессия с шагом 2 считается по формуле:

```
S(i) = (a(i)(0) + a(i)(k-1))) * k / 2, где a(i)(0) - первый элемент i-й строки
k - число элементов в строке (очевидно k = i + 1)
a(i)(k-1) - последний элемент в строке
```

Осталось найти a(i)(0):
По сути это (сумма количеств элементов в верхних строках - 1)-й элемент последовательности нечётных чисел (так как нас интересует первый элемент после предыдущей строки)

Номер элемента вычисляем по формуле прогрессии:

```
n = i * (i + 1) / 2
```

Формула нечётных чисел:

```
v(n) = 2 * n + 1
```

Подставив получим:

```
a(i)(0) = v(n) = 2 * (i * (i + 1) / 2) + 1 = i^2 + i + 1
```

Откуда получим:

```
 a(i)(k-1) = v(n) + 2 * (k - 1) = i^2 + i + 2 * k - 1
```

Подставив в формулу для S(i) получим:

```
S(i) = (i^2 + i + 1 + i^2 + i + 2 * (i + 1) - 1) * (i + 1) / 2
S(i) = (i^2 + 2 * i + 1) * (i + 1) = (i + 1)^3
```

Получается можно считать сумму по формуле напрямую:

```
S(i) = (i + 1)^3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> strs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0, c = 5, num = 1; i < c; i++) {
    for (int l = c - i; l > 0; l--) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) {
        System.out.print(11 > num ? num + "   " : num + "  ");
        list.add(num);
        num += 2;
    }
    strs.add(i, list);
    System.out.println();
}
strs.stream().forEach(map -> {
    System.out.println(map.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
});
```

Вывод:

> 1
>   8
>   27
>   64
>   125

Можно конечно было сделать и расчетами по формулам и т.д., но мне было лень, по этому запилил на коллекциях, их проще будет передавать, если вдруг понадобится.

Ну и сама функция, для вывода индексов строки:

```
public static int sum(int n) {
    return strs.get(n-1).stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}
```

Вывод:

```
System.out.print(sum(2)); //8
System.out.print(sum(5)); //125
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас значения никуда не записываются, значит либо завести переменную, повторить циклы и складывать с этой переменной значение, либо завести все куда-то. То, что вы вывели треугольник - просто визуализация